# Network connection issues with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, networkmanager, wicd

After reading through several threads on here about network connection issues, and trying to solve it on my own, to no avail, I thought I'd post the problem here.

I have an HP Chromebook 14 running Ubuntu 12.04. A little over a week ago, shortly after installing Ubuntu 12.04 (Unity Desktop), my internet connection began going out, always after rebooting. Sometimes I can connect, but after rebooting I have no idea whether I'll have any connection when I try to connect again.

After some research, I decided to uninstall network manager and install WICD. The inconsistency of internet connection continues. I should add that I know its not the wireless router because all my other devices connect just fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions given what I've already tried?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the network in /etc/network/interfaces directly ?

Comment: I have not. I'm a little new to the OS. How would I configure it in the terminal?